# Mercurial - Auto updating of a local repo after push to remote repo

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

We use Mercurial and Kiln for source control. Here is what I want to accomplish but have not had any luck unfortunately

Let's say we have 3 repos in play. One remote (https://company.kiln.com), one local on my dev machine, and one local on an FTP server that an IT person picks up installation scripts from

What I want to happen:

After I push a change from my local repo to the remote repo, I want the local repo on the FTP server to auto update so I don't have to keep copying over new files every time they change. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Can you just schedule a task on the ftp to issue `hg pull ....` every 15 min or so? Otherwise hg [hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) as well as [kilns](http://help.fogcreek.com/8111/web-hooks-integrating-kiln-with-other-services) are probably where you need to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it. And must to use [hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) on [central repository side](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.Any_way_to_.27hg_push.27_and_have_an_automatic_.27hg_update.27_on_the_remote_server.3F)

You have <strike>two</strike>three ways:

1. Pull style: `changegroup` hook on server connects to FTP (over SSH) and perform [all needed actions](https://beeznest.wordpress.com/2010/06/03/automatically-updating-a-working-copy-on-a-remote-server-using%C2%A0mercurial/)
2. Push style: `changegroup` hook on server push it's repo to FTP (FTP must have pushable Mercurial server)
3. BEST CHOICE: **Use [autosync extension](https://bitbucket.org/obensonne/hg-autosync/wiki/Home) on DEV and FTP**

Comment: Early testing leads me to believe the autosync extension may be exactly what I was looking for. I will post more detailed information later and maybe even draw up my working example